# Can I retrieve non shared DE rows from Parent BU using WS Proxy?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to retrieve rows from a non shared DE which is present in Child BU. This has to be from Parent BU. Is this feasible?

Is it possible to retrieve non Shared DE rows with impersonation from different BU?

Below is the sample code snippet that I'm using.

```
Platform.Load('core', '1');
var mid = 'mid'; //mid of childbu
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var deExtKey = 'external-key'; //external key of the de in child bu
var cols = ["Eid","firstName","lastName"]; 


prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid });
var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols);

Write(Stringify(desc));
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
{"Status":"Error: Data extension does not exist: undefined","RequestID":"reqID","Results":null,"HasMoreRows":false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that via using the setClientId method on the WSProxy object.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
prox.setClientId({ "ID": "Your child BU MID" });

</script>
```

Note that, you can:

- Impersonate a Child BU from the Parent BU

but **not** impersonate the parent BU from a Child BU

Reference: [Impersonation via WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_WSProxy_impersonate.html)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not able to retrieve non shared DE rows.

Comment: @AravindPulagam you mean you could be able to retrieve DE records from the child BU and when you impersonated the child BU from the Parent one like above you didn't get the records successfully retrieved?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting Data extension doesn't exist error. I mean, will that work? I'm trying to retrieve rows from a de which is not shared. If it works for you, can you share a sample code snippet?

Comment: @AravindPulagam It will work. Have you attempted to impersonate the child BU and retrieve the records yet? Which error are you referring to? You need to show what you tried first, SFSE is not a free code service

Comment: Sorry for the way I had written this post. Updated the post with the code snippets.

Comment: @AravindPulagam Thank you for updating code in your post. It seems the variable name `deExtKey` for DE customer key is different with the one using in the retrieve call `deCustKey`. Can you fix it and retry?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That's the issue. It worked. This makes me look really dumb.

Comment: @AravindPulagam If you feel the answer is useful, please mark it as an accepted answer, thank you

Comment: Definitely, Quick question: Can you impersonate one child bu from another child bu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142479/discussion-between-duc-le-and-aravind-pulagam).